# Oracle table from SAS dataset

Tags: oracle, sas, dataset

I was trying to create Oracle tables from SAS datasets. I am successful in many cases, but am stuck for a particular dataset. I am providing the log file below. I am working with SAS 9 and Oracle 11.2.0.1.0 on Linux.

Any suggestions?

```
1          libname dibsdata "/data2/dibyendu/Jan_9/on_demand/";
NOTE: Libref DIBSDATA was successfully assigned as follows:
      Engine:        V9
      Physical Name: /data2/dibyendu/Jan_9/on_demand
2          libname myora oracle user=sasuser password=XXXXXXXXXX path=CIOEDATA ;
NOTE: Libref MYORA was successfully assigned as follows:
      Engine:        ORACLE
      Physical Name: CIOEDATA
3          data myora.on_demand;
4              set dibsdata.on_demand;
5          run;

NOTE: SAS variable labels, formats, and lengths are not written to DBMS tables.
ERROR: Error attempting to CREATE a DBMS table. ERROR: ORACLE execute error: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier..
NOTE: The DATA step has been abnormally terminated.
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
NOTE: SAS set option OBS=0 and will continue to check statements. This might cause NOTE: No observations in data set.
WARNING: The data set MYORA.ON_DEMAND may be incomplete.  When this step was stopped there were 0 observations and 48 variables.
ERROR: ROLLBACK issued due to errors for data set MYORA.ON_DEMAND.DATA.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.06 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds


ERROR: Errors printed on page 1.
2                                                          The SAS System                           17:00 Wednesday, January 9, 2013


NOTE: SAS Institute Inc., SAS Campus Drive, Cary, NC USA 27513-2414
NOTE: The SAS System used:
      real time           1.24 seconds
      cpu time            0.04 seconds
```

Comment: Looks like an issue with your data values not meeting a particular oracle column constraint? What is oracle error ORA-00904?

Comment: Try checking if some of the variables in the original dataset have names that are reserved words on Oracle.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle error **ORA-00904** means you are trying to create a table with an invalid column name.  Most likely you have a SAS variable with a name longer that 30 characters or is an Oracle reserved word.  For example, the two variables in this SAS dataset are illegal in Oracle:

```
data a;
  column_name_too_long_for_oracle = 1;
  date = today(); /* This is a reserved word */
run;
```

Here is [the Oracle 11g Reserved Words list](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/ap_keywd001.htm).  Check the variable names in your SAS dataset and rename them to something legal in Oracle.  If example, if the offender is a SAS variable named **DATE**, you might try this:

```
data myora.on_demand;
   set dibsdata.on_demand(rename=(DATE=PROJ_DATE));
run;
```

Comment: Many thanks, dperetin and Bob Duell. I discovered that there was a variable called "index" and there was another variable with an unusually long name. I renamed these two variables and that solved the problem. Regards,